# Xcode 9 beta 2 storyboard is full of errors

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode9-beta

I recently upgraded to xcode 9 beta 2 and my storyboard is full of errors, it was completely fine on xcode 8. I attached a screenshot of it. Is there any fix for that

[image: Storyboard errors]

[image: Storyboard errors 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These warnings are new in Xcode 9 beta 3, and identify real potential problems when your app is running in a different language. Like other auto layout issues that appear in the document outline, click the yellow triangle to get a popover with options to resolve the issues. Alternatively, there may be different changes that are more appropriate to your specific layout.

[image: issue resolution popover]

The warnings appear in their entirety in the Issues navigator. For what it's worth, there are already bugs tracking the text truncation in the document outline, and the red (instead of yellow) arrow images.

If your app is not actually being deployed in multiple languages, you could disable these by unchecking "Base" in the Localization section of the File inspector. However, fixing the warnings instead of ignoring them is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

If all the issues are related to **Localization**, try moving the `Main.storyboard` file outside of `Base.lproj` folder.

Comment: hey i already tried this but after that m not able to access my Main.storyboard file in xcode.Please help. My Xcode Version is Version 9.1 (9B55).

Comment: @deltami could you clarify what exactly you mean by "not able to access"?